# Is "very" an acceptable answer?

Tags: questions

If you ask a question starting with "are you...", for example:

> Are you hungry?

Is it acceptable to answer with:

> Very.

I'm not sure if it's acceptable though I've heard it used.

Comment: This totally depends on context. We'd know what was meant, but if you were saying it to an important person, it probably wouldn't be that acceptable. To your acquaintances/peers, it's fine (so long as the meaning is clear.)

Answer (score 4):

To build on @marcellothearcane's answer:

The formal and grammatically correct answer would be:

> Yes, thank you, I am very hungry.

However, in colloquial English (especially spoken English), that's a very cumbersome answer.  It's longer than the question, afer all!  Therefore, following common practices concerning [conversational-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/conversational-deletion/info), the vast majority of that sentence is dropped and "very" becomes an acceptable answer.

Note, though, the @marcellothearcane is very correct in that the circumstances may not prefer the use of "very" as an answer.  The more formal the engagement, the less likely it will be appreciated.

Comment: And it practice, that exchange could be simplified even further to: "Hungry? Very."

Comment: nice - have some rep!

Comment: +1, But...you  have a typo in the sentence containing conversational - deletion.  The typo is actually pretty funny.

Comment: Consider also why you're being asked.  Is the person going to offer you some of his sandwich?  Or suggest you stop for dinner on the way home from work, when you already have plans?